# C++ how to pass a line of HEX to string?

Tags: c++

So whenever I receive a message a receive in this format:

```
7B 22 6D 69 6E 22 3A 37 22 2C 22 6D 61 78 22 3A 39 7D
```

The code looks like this:

```
    char rcv[64];
    int i = 0;
    while (modem.available()) {
      rcv[i++] = (char)modem.read();
    }
    String data_received= "";
    for (unsigned int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
      data_received += 
      Serial.print(rcv[j] >> 4, HEX);
      Serial.print(rcv[j] & 0xF, HEX);
      Serial.print(" ");
    }
  }
```

That string data_received I would like to make it look like this:

```
{"min":7","max":9}
```

But have no idea how to convert them from hex to String and join them together.

By the way this is Arduino and library is: [MKRWAN](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/MKRWANAvailable)

Comment: `String data_received= rcv;` doesn't work?

Comment: In order to answer, it helps to know the definition of the types you are using (String, Serial). Can you list the libraries your code is using? It looks like the Arduino SDK?

Comment: @NathanOliver Nope because it will steal data from other places in memory.

Comment: @kmac it is indeed Arduino and the library is MKRWAN.

Comment: This line `data_received +=` is incomplete.

Comment: Ah.  That's right, it's not null terminated. Use `char rcv[64]{};` and it should work as long as you never receive more than 63 bytes of data.

Comment: I'm not sure about String, but std::string needs a null termination '\0'. I see there is an example String msg = Serial.readStringUntil('\n'); here: https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/MKRWANRead

Comment: Also, you probably want to replace your prints with just Serial.print(rcv[j]); so they print as ASCII instead of hex.

Comment: I think both your answers work fine, but this damn thing sometimes loses Serial.prints along the way so it's getting hard to test them... Thanks fellas.

Comment: Yep String `data_received= rcv` with `String data_received= rcv;` worked thanks guys with

Comment: Is it me, or is your code actually dumping the hexadecimal values of the received characters? Do not do that if you want the original bytes: `for (unsigned int j = 0; j < i; j++) { Serial.print(rcv[j]); }`

Comment: @kmac "*`std::string` needs a null termination '\0'*" - only if you are assigning it a null-terminated `char*` and not specifying the string length.  `std::string` has a constructor that accepts a length.

Answer (score 0):

Overlooking the fact that there is nothing preventing you from a buffer overrun on rcv, do this after the while loop:

```
rcv[i] = 0;
String data_received = rcv;
```

But **please**, make sure you guard your loop so that it will not try to take more than 63 characters.